# Better way to produce V\llap{--}

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Is there a better way to get the symbol produced by `V\llap{--}`? I need it in math mode. The symbol is someitmes used to represent volume. The above hack is not the right symbol but something close.

Comment: How about `\forall`? Does it fit your requirements?

Comment: @CountZero I need the dash to extend beyond the V.

Comment: Can you please upload (provide a link to) an image showing the desired symbol used in context?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina the symbol is usually used when writing Reynolds transport equation. This [pdf file](http://www.geofys.uu.se/files/teacher/FM_Lecture4.pdf) shows it in use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\volume}{{\ooalign{\hfil$V$\hfil\cr\kern0.08em--\hfil\cr}}}
\begin{document}
$\volume(abc)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A better implementation, where the dash is built as above, but over a phantom V; the real one is added later, so subscripts and superscripts are placed with respect to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\volume}{\text{\volumedash}V}
\newcommand{\volumedash}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \ooalign{\hfil\hphantom{$\m@th V$}\hfil\cr\kern0.08em--\hfil\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$d\volume(abc)$

$x^{}_{\volume}$

$\volume_x$

$V_x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are kerning issues here if you want a subscript, as in `\volume_n`. Also, as a differential, `\mathrm{d}\volume` has incorrect spacing. This issue is addressed in [a solution to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393758/125871). Are there any issues with that solution?

Comment: @SandyG The subscript problem is solved by using a phantom V in the `\ooalign` and a real V afterwards. Thanks for pointing to  the weakness of the original macro.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing, but found it a bit distracting to have the cross extend beyond the lines of the V. I came up with an alternative approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Vol}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\ensuremath{A}}}

\begin{document}
    Let $\Vol$ represent system volume.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Inspired by @egreg's answer. You can adjust the position parameters in the code.

```
\ooalign{$V$\cr\raisebox{0.15em}{\kern0.04em--}\cr}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another simple alternative using `\makebox` command with the same name of @egreg's named `\volume`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\volume}{\makebox[1pt][l]{$-$}V}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{d\volume(x,y,z)}{dz}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get it on Google Slides:

```
  V\kern-0.8em\raise0.3ex-
```

Resulting in:

[image: cross V]

In Google Docs Addon [Math equations](https://github.com/brendena/MathEquationsGoogleSlide), many of the commands, in the neat solutions provided here, are not supported: \ooalign, \raisebox, \cr, \hfill. Instead, using a simple \raise and \kern helps. This is not a generic solution that handles sub- and super-scripts. In slides, we normally want a quick solution that can be easily edited locally, and the expressions are small and local to a slide. Playing around with kern and raise can still work for sub- and super-scripts.

Comment: This doesn't work in (La)TeX. It might work on Google Slides but that's off-topic here.