# Bug in xelatex + unicode+math + vphantom

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode-math

This question is a simplified version of [a slightly more complicated problem with XITS Math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296061/bug-in-xelatex-unicode-math-xits-vphantom):
Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\(|^a\) \(\vphantom{|}^a\)

\(|^a\) \(\mathord{\vphantom{|}}^a\)

\(|^a\) \(\mbox{\vphantom{$|$}}^a\)
\end{document}
```

In the first line, the vertical positions of the two occurrences of 'a' are the same when compiling with lualatex (which is expected) but not when compiling with xelatex (which I consider a bug). The second and third lines represent unsuccessful attempts to repair. Any hints?

[image: result of compiling with xelatex]

Comment: A box can never be the nucleus for a math atom, so it cannot receive superscripts. You have to brace the `\vphantom`.

Comment: Like this: \mbox{{\vphantom{$|$}}}^a ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Additionally, there are fontdimen scaling problems in XeTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549/why-is-the-fraction-off-the-math-axis-in-xetex

Comment: @egreg: \mbox{{\vphantom{$|$}}}^a gives the same result as \mbox{\vphantom{$|$}}^a for me.

Comment: @FrankFeuerstern It should be `{\mbox{\vphantom{$|$}}}^a` or just `{\vphantom{$|$}}^a`.

Comment: @Henri Meike: {\mbox{\vphantom{$|$}}}^a still gives the same result for me. {\vphantom{$|$}}^a doesn't compile.

Comment: @egreg: “A box can never be the nucleus for a math atom”???

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Right, a `\phantom` can't. Try `$\displaystyle\vphantom{\sum}^x\sum\nolimits^x$\bye`

Comment: @egreg: So you actually meant:  A `\mathchoice` can never be the nuclues of a math atom, so it cannot receive superscripts.  This is true.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Yes, that's the thing! Never do things when you are also coping more important ones. `;-)` I can confirm my opinion that `\mathchoice` is the most unfortunate aspect of TeX.

Comment: With amsmath instead of unicode-math, the first line works great.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/87/
https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/267

Comment: The two math lists produced by `$\vphantom{|}^a$` and by `$\mathchoice{\setbox2=\null \ht2=7.5pt  \dp2=2.5pt  \box2}{\setbox2=\null \ht2=7.5pt  \dp2=2.5pt  \box2}{\setbox2=\null \ht2=5.24998pt \dp2=1.75pt \box2}{\setbox2=\null \ht2=3.75pt \dp2=1.25pt \box2}^a$` seem identical, yet their translation to a horizontal list is different (but only with __unicode-math__): quite puzzling… :-/

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti : As of today, I'm afraid I'm done: unfortunately, I do know know enough of TeX to understand or debug your code.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I think the difference is that in the first case a math symbol is typeset (for building `\box0` that's later used for setting the dimensions of `\box2`).

Comment: @egreg: But it is typeset while constructing the math list: how can this influence the conversion from math list to horizontal list?  In any case, also adding `\setbox0=\hbox{${|}$}` to all four branches of my hand-crafted `\mathchoice` doesn’t change the output.  But I think it’s enough for now: let us think again about this mystery tomorrow.  **EDIT:**  Just found it: add `\setbox0=\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle{|}$}` to the *last* branch and you’ll see!  But how can this happen?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti A very mysterious bug indeed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the bug is fixed in TL2017.

Comment: @HenriMenke it looks as if the problem is not completly resolved. Superscripts works, but subscripts can still be shifted slightly differently. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374902/2388 or try in Gustavo Mezzetti's answer `_t`  instead of `^a`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, that is kind of disappointing.  Well, the future belongs to LuaTeX then I guess.  I would leave this question closed because it is explicitly about superscripts and these seem to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I am making this an answer only because it doesn’t fit in a comment:  It looks like XeTeX “remembers” the math style that was in force when it last typeset a symbol inside a formula, and continues to apply it for choosing certain `\fontdimen` parameters in subsequent formulas as long as they begin with an atom whose nucleus is empty (or contains an empty math list, which has the same effect).  Consider

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\begin{document}
Just try:
$^a$ $\scriptscriptstyle x$ $^a$ $\mathchoice{}{}{}{}^a$ $x^a$ $^a$
\end{document}
```

whose output is

[image: Output of the code]

However, this only happens when the **unicode-math** package is loaded.

This error seems to occur during the process of transforming a math list into its horizontal equivalent, as if XeTeX failed to initialize the “current style” in some situations, or more precisely some information pertaining to the choice of the `\fontdimen` parameters involved in typesetting the superscript.  But this is only a guess (after all, the question asks for “any hints”).

Where does the behavior described in the question come from, then?  Well, `\vphantom{|}`, when used in math mode, invokes a primitive command of TeX called `\mathchoice`, which—to put it simply—typesets the “|” character in all the four math styles (`\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`) in order to figure out how much tall the phantom should be in each of the four styles.  Thus, the last thing `\vphantom{|}` does is to typeset `$\scriptscriptstyle |$`, and when the closing `$` is sensed, this formula is translated into a horizontal list (and saved into a temporary box, but this doesn’t matter here); if our guess is correct, this leaves in some place the information that the `\fontdimen` parameters should be chosen for a “current style” equal to `\scriptscriptstyle`.  Then, (Xe)TeX returns to the (still empty) math list that it was constructing when it saw the `\vphantom{|}`, and appends a “four-way choice” node to it, containing the four versions of the phantom, one for each of the possible styles.

Next comes the `^a`.  Now, a fact that seems to be easily forgotten is that a math list can contain several kinds of nodes (*The TeXbook* lists them all at the bottom of page 157), but that *only atoms can carry sub/superscripts*; a “four-way choice” node can’t, so (page 291, description of the “superscript” command) an Ord atom with an empty nucleus is appended to the list, and the “*a*” becomes it superscript.  At this point the math list looks like this:

```
\mathchoice
D\mathord
D.\hbox(7.5+2.5)x0.0
T\mathord
T.\hbox(7.5+2.5)x0.0
S\mathord
S.\hbox(5.24998+1.75)x0.0
s\mathord
s.\hbox(3.75+1.25)x0.0
\mathord
^\fam0
```

This list is then converted to its horizontal equivalent.  According to our hypthesis, XeTeX still has some “dirty” variable saying that the `\fontdimen` parameters should be those of `\scriptscriptstyle`; at this point, everything goes as in the case of `$\mathchoice{}{}{}{}^a$` in our code, above: for some reason, the “four-way choice” node containing just empty boxes does *not* reset the `\fontdimen` information, and, according to Rule 4 of Appendix G, leaves just an Ord atom without sub/superscript, which is processed by Rules 14, 17, and 18, yielding simply an empty box of some (unimportant) height; then comes the Ord atom with empty nucleus, and Rule 14 just passes it over to Rule 17, that in turn, being the nucleus empty, goes on to Rule 18, which is the rule that takes care of positioning the sub/superscript.  Thus we see that, in our hypotheses, Rule 18 is applied while the `\fontdimen` information is still “dirty”.

(Deep breath.)

Comment: This is essentially the same bug as this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549/why-is-the-fraction-off-the-math-axis-in-xetex

Comment: Alas, I understand zero from your remarks---which is completely due to my ignorance. I guess, if you could push xetex developers in https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/87 a bit, one might have a slightly higher chance of repairing. But so far, I apologize a lot for not being able to provide any useful information.