# XeLaTeX does not load newtxmath with LinuxLibertine (sometimes)

Tags: math-mode, xetex, footnotes, libertine

I'd like to use `newtxmath` along with `LinuxLibertine` under `XeLaTeX`. What maybe sounds simple really drives me crazy. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
with mathmode: & without mathmode: \\
$1+2=3$ & 1+2=3 \\
\end{tabular}

Footnote\footnote{}$^,$\footnote{$123$}$^,$\footnote{}

\end{document}
```

The result, however, doesn't show the intended math font:
[image]

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
>   (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.3.4)

With PDFLaTeX everything looks fine:
[image]

Now, the real puzzle starts when compiling this with `XeLaTeX` under `cygwin`:
[image]

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Cygwin)
>   (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.10.12)

The math font seems to be the right one, but in the case of multiple footnotes, the footnote numbers in the text are messed up if one of them contains a mathematical environment (or `\url`)! The last comma and the `3` are slightly lower than the preceding marks.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `newtxmath` package has a peculiar way of setting the `operators` symbol font when XeTeX or LuaTeX is used, which explains the problems with numbers.

You can use the standard font by doing some adjustments, but in this case the strange bug with XeTeX shows up, see [Bug in xelatex + unicode+math + vphantom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296177/bug-in-xelatex-unicodemath-vphantom)

There's a way out, which is patching `\textsuperscript` so it typesets some math in text style (but the bug might show up elsewhere, too).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\xpretocmd{\textsuperscript}
 {{\sbox0{$\textstyle x$}}}
 {}{}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}%
  \SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{b}{n}%
}

%% Alternative
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
%\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
%\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
with mathmode: & without mathmode: \\
$1+2=3$ & 1+2=3 \\
\end{tabular}

Footnote\footnote{123}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{$123$}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{123}

\end{document}
```

<sup>(Note: the output has been produced with `\textheight=3cm`)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's like magic. `xetex` now behaves as desired (both in win32 and cygwin). Still, this is very confusing and does not boost my confidence in `xetex`/`newtxmath`.

Comment: There's  a related bug when using `\url` in footnotes, just with `libertine` and `xetex` (hence even when I don't use `newtxmath`). Your patch solves this for me too: `\xpretocmd{\textsuperscript}
 {{\sbox0{$\textstyle x$}}}
 {}{}`.