# \scriptstyle affects \overline

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

The following code

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX 
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{unicode-math,mathtools}
\begin{document}
    $\overline{A}\overline{A}\mathrlap{A}$
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

## Going deeper

Through some experiments, I found that `mathtools` and `\mathclap` are not to blame.

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX 
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
    $\overline{B}\overline{B}\hbox{$\scriptstyle B$}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This disagreement is restricted to

- The package`unicode-math`
- XeLaTeX (LuaLaTeX is fine)
- The first `\overline` (The second is fine. `\underline` is fine)
- `\hbox` containing `scriptstyle` and something printable.

One may also try this

```
$\overline{C}\overline{C}\mathchoice{}{}{}{\hbox{$\scriptstyle C$}}$
```

I have no idea how to go deeper. Any idea?

Comment: Very good detective work!

Comment: Oh, you're using XeLaTeX.  Keep in mind that `\fontdimen`s are messed up there.  This is basically another incarnation of the problem reported here: [Why is the fraction off the math axis in XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549).  Use LuaLaTeX instead.

Comment: Thanks for reference. For me I can easily get over this case by case. I will leave it here. (By the way, in your example the fraction is **always** off. And here, it becomes even weirder.)

Comment: @HenriMenke: I guess [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296177) concerned another incarnation of the same bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been resolved. Both in TeXLive2017 and in a current miktex the output of a xelatex compilation is fine:

[image]